How can a HTTP request to be UNAUTHORIZED in anything but NODE JS/JS
I'm reverse engeneering a API to consume data almost with no webscraping, when I do in node/js
fetch(url,{method:'POST'})

I get a json data (status code 200) but when I do this exact same request on python, reqbin, ARC etc I get 403 unauthorized.
How can this happen? I think it's due to the chrome engine in node js.

It can't, the server knows nothing about the client, other than the request itself. The two requests must have something different, or the server is limiting due to something else.

fetch('https://api.casadosdados.com.br/v2/public/cnpj/search', {
method: 'POST'})

Cookies and/or headers probably are different, less likely to matter is the user-agent.

add https, the stackoverflow is removing it
